# Javascript Event Delegation - Click Event Not Bubbling As Expected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm probably making a really simple error somewhere, but for some reason the event doesn't seem to be bubbling properly.

The Javascript is fairly trivial, uses jQuery at the moment for ease of DOM manipulation but don't want to rely on it for event handling.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  document.onclick = function(event) {

    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    var target_class= target.className.toLowerCase();

    if(target_class.indexOf('test_class') >= 0)
    {
        $('#log').append('<p>clicked!</p>');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

  }
```

});

The HTML for the purpose of demonstration is similarly trivial.

```
  <a href="" class="test_class">text</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="test_class"><img src="http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/9111/trianglesl.png"></a>

  <div id="log">
    <h3>Log</h3>
  </div>
```

As you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/SuBQQ/1/ the hyperlink works, whereas clicking on the image doesn't trigger the correct event, and instead uses the event on the image (which I thought would then bubble up the DOM but it appears I'm wrong).

Am I doing this all wrong, or just missing something small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that clicking on the image sets the target to the img DOM object and then your code tests to see if test_class is on that object.  But, the image doesn't have that class.  If you set a breakpoint or an alert inside the event handler, you can see that it is working - it's just your test for the presence of the class name on the image that fails.

The event is handled by the  tag and the page location is changed so there's no opportunity for the document event handler to do anything with it.  If you change the href on the  link to "#" so it doesn't change the page as an experiment and put some debugging in your click handler, you will see that it does bubble up to the document.   But, in your jsfiddle, it doesn't work because the  link is processing the event before the document and changing the page.

See this for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7a9Ha/.

Comment: I understand this, but assumed that the event would bubble to the hyperlink?

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer.  In a nutshell, the <a> link is changing the page before the event gets to the document and even if the event gets to the document, the target is still the img which doesn't have the class on it.  So, you have to fix both.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. I assumed that the target would change as the event bubbled, looks like I've made a fundamental mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00, your JSFiddle has the exact same problematic behavior as the OP's.

Comment: @AlexQueue - you missed the point.  When one clicks on the image, the target of the click is the image and the image does not have the desired class so the test fails.

Comment: Correct. I'm confused then as to what your jsfiddle is supposed to differently compared to the OP's.

Comment: @AlexQueue - I don't remember.  This was 18 months ago.

Comment: @jfriend00 Exactly. I think something changed so that it now no longer works as intended. Just an FYI.